# bash variable expansion in assigning to another variable

Tags: bash

I think this is fairly basic, but there seems to be something fundamental that I'm not understanding. Any explanation is much appreciated.

When I do this on the command line:

```
$ export MYPATH=$HOME/somepath/something
$ echo $MYPATH
```

I get `/home/myname/somepath/something` as expected.

But then when I have this in a script, where it looks like this:

```
MYPATH=$HOME/somepath/something
source $MYPATH -whatever
```

I get an error that says

```
/bin/sh: $HOME/somepath/something: No such file or directory
```

But then when I hard code the full path in the script like `MYPATH=/home/myname/somepath/something` it works fine.

Obviously it's not expanding the `$HOME` variable but I've been googling around and I can't seem to figure out why, or how to do it the right way. I would prefer not to hard-code the path because different users will use this script and that's kind of the whole point of having the `$HOME` variable, right?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What you are doing should work.  Perhaps you made a trivial typo, or $HOME does not have the value you expect

Comment: You need to have somehow escaped the dollar sign to get that error message; there's no way to disable parameter expansion in general. Unlike globs, which are treated literally if they don't expand, *any* unset parameter expands to the empty string.

Comment: Did you actually write `MYPATH='$HOME/somepath/something'`? Note that you should be writing `source "$MYPATH" ... ` to prevent the expansion from being subject to word-splitting or pathname expansion.

Comment: (And, you should be using `.`, not `source`, in a script that might be run using `sh`, even if you are *sure* that `sh` is really `bash`.)

Comment: ok, maybe that isn't my problem. Potentially important detail: this is actually in `crontab`. Could that be the problem? More specifically, my crontab has in it 
`PYTHON3=$HOME/.conda/envs/myenv/bin/python3` (newline) `0 0 * * * $PYTHON3 /fullpath/script.py`
and when it tries to run I get the `...No such file or directory` error. But when I replace `$HOME` with `/home/myname` it works. Thanks!